# How can I copy this string while making these modifications

Tags: php, regex, string

I'm trying to perform a string manipulation on this string. I have an algorithm in mind, but not sure about the php syntax.

```
<who    not="p" what="v" />
<cares  i="n"   want="m" />
<target my="t"  what="iwant" />
```

Between each start and end pair `<` and `/>`, the string `my="t"` may or may not exist (in this example it only exists on the third line). If it doesn't exist, I want to copy the whole `< />` as is. If it exists, I want to add `<something />` after it. So I want this string to look like this

```
<who    not="p" what="v" />
<cares  i="n"   want="m" />
<target my="t"  what="iwant" /><something />
```

What complicates the situation is that `my="t"` seems to not have a standard position, it could be anywhere between `< />`. Any suggestions how to do this with php? I'm thinking regex

Comment: Since it looks like you're working with XML, why not use an XML parser such as [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I think you could use regex, or simply combination of substr & strpos to seperate the `<... />`

You can use [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php) to determine if `my="t"` appears in a string or not, then perform the approriate action.

Actually, I think that breaking your task into smaller tasks, is more simple and easier to refactor than trying to get all in one shot with a magical regex.

Comment: +1 but I think your answer is missing a piece. How do I divide the string to multiple `< />`?

Comment: loop through the string, first find the strpos of "/>", then use substr to cut it out.

Comment: @park: you can take a look at my quick code here: http://codepad.org/Dyk0VhKz . You still need to insert a while loop to determine a "/>" position multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
$l = array('<who    not="p" what="v" />','<cares  i="n"   want="m" />','<target my="t"  what="iwant" />');

foreach ($l as $str) {
  $str = preg_replace('#(<.*?my="t".*? />)#', "$1<something />", $str);
  echo $str,"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
<who    not="p" what="v" />
<cares  i="n"   want="m" />
<target my="t"  what="iwant" /><something />
```